# Performance and Monitoring tools for .NET

Tags: .net, etw

What are the different ways to identify the monitor and diagonsis of Windows/Web applications performance(I need tools/applications provided by Microsoft, not third party tools).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some really amazingly helpful tools in the .NET ecosystem - what is the reason for insisting on Microsoft-branded things here? That is going to make this very hard...

Comment: The reason being - in my organization it will be difficult for us to use third party tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft itself uses the [Windows Performance Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx). Microsoft uses the WPT for example during the [development of the Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/16/internet-explorer-performance-lab-reliably-measuring-browser-performance.aspx).

You can find an introduction here: [Measuring Browser Performance with the Windows Performance Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/21/measuring-browser-performance-with-the-windows-performance-tools.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008/2010 provides build-in performance analysis tools (profiling)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the performance monitor (perfmon.exe) to monitor the different performance counters. I myself use this, and quite a few tools originated from sysinternals (Process explorer and Debugview). Sysinternals has been bought by Microsoft, if I'm not mistaken, so now the tools are provided by Microsoft.